# use a timer to send data to serial port C#

Tags: c#, timer

I want to listen on a comport but every ten minutes send the word "PING" to that comport.  I can listen with no issue but I cannot figure out how to get the timer to send on the same open port.  If I try to call the timer event and put the code to write to the com port, I get the error: 'The name 'myport' does not exist in the current context.'  I know WHY I am getting the error, but I am not sure how to format the code to use the timer to use the same comport that is open.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    //public static void Main()
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;


        {
            SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();  //Setting up the Serial 
Port
            myport.BaudRate = 9600;
            myport.PortName = "COM4";
            myport.Open();

            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {
                myport.WriteLine("             Your are Now Connected to 
GDC-IoT Number 1");
                myport.WriteLine("         ALETS - Actionable Law Enforcment 
Technology Software");
            }


            while (true)
            {


                string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();     // Read Serial Data
                Console.WriteLine(data_rx);


            }
        }
    }

                public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, 
ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        myport.WriteLine("PING");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I looked at Peter Duniho's questions and not sure how mine is a duplicate.  Can you point me to the question that may be a duplicate so I can update my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `myport` defined in the `Main` function, so it's local to that function. Try declaring it outside the method, at the class level, so that it's accessible to ALL methods:

```
class Program
{
    private static SerialPort myPort;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new Timer { Interval = 5000, Enabled = true };
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        myPort = new SerialPort { BaudRate = 9600, PortName = "COM4" };
        myPort.Open();

        if (myPort.IsOpen)
        {
            myPort.WriteLine("You are are now connected to GDC-IoT Number 1");
            myPort.WriteLine("ALETS - Actionable Law Enforcment Technology Software");
        }

        // Listen to serial port
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myPort.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myPort == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Port has not yet been assigned");
        }
        else if (!myPort.IsOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Port is not open");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending ping...");
            myPort.WriteLine("PING");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rufus you rock! thanks..I couldn't figure out how to make it accessible to all variables, but that worked!  Much appreciated!